# Http 404 when trying to get files from GitLab API

Tags: git, rest, gitlab

I have a bitnami VM with gitlab 6.1.0.0 and I'm trying to get the files of a specific project from the rest API.

I tried to do something like this:

```
http://<my-git-lab-server>/api/v3/projects/12/repository/files?private_token=<my_token>
```

Of course `12` marks the project id which exists. I got as a response `404 - page not found` (BTW - the customized 404 page of gitlab)

I saw in the documentation that you need to pass parameters. So I used `tree` to get the files, like this:

```
http://<my-git-lab-server>/api/v3/projects/12/repository/tree?private_token=<my_token>
```

And I got for example this file (along with other files):

```
[... some files here ... , {"name": "test.py", "type": "blob", "mode": "100644", "id": <some-id-here>}]
```

Then I tried the same url as before and added the `file_path` and `ref` parameters as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/repository_files.md) and it looked like this:

```
http://<my-git-lab-server>/api/v3/projects/12/repository/files?file_path=test.py&ref=master&private_token=<my_token>
```

I also tried `"test.py"` (with quotations). I tried using `master` as ref as this file is found in the master branch. Hope that's what I should put there.

Anyway, still getting 404 not found. I'm not sure how to get the file correctly.

The task is to copy some projects content to a new gitlab server (of a different version as well) - if that changes anything.

Comment: This answer helped me with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24210596/601466

Answer (score 1):

You mention you're using Gitlab v6.1. According to the history of https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/repository_files.md the `/api/v3/projects/{id}/repository/files` end point arrived in version 6.6. It looks like the `/api/v3/projects/{id}/repository/tree` endpoint arrived in version 5.3. So to get the files API functionality, you'll need to upgrade Gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not possible to use `GET /projects/:id/repository/files` on version 6.1, it's possible to download the file using `GET /projects/:id/repository/blobs/:sha`. Take a look here: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/repositories.md