# python-gitlab error 404 when get file from subdirectory of project

Tags: python, gitlab

With library python-gitlab
response is **404** when i try:

```
file = project.files.get(file_path='test_dir/test_file_created_manually', ref='main')
```

but file exists(!)

```
items = project.repository_tree(path='test_dir')
```

returns this file with
'path': 'test_dir/test_file_created_manually'

when i work with root catalog in project - all OK with files

Final goal is create files in subdirs, so project.files.create is with 404 too, not create automatically file with path in 'file_path' attr.

May be problem is in Gitlab version 13.12.12., like in
[Http 404 when trying to get files from GitLab API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626610/http-404-when-trying-to-get-files-from-gitlab-api)
but project.files.create works in root catalog of project, but not in subcatalog (

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/214349 - Repository Files API not working with subdirectories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On nginx was not set parameter $request_uri for proxy_pass
(on apache same problem with AllowEncodedSlashes)